# ERROR: Cannot find symbol -- How do I get my class to compile when it depends on a class in a subfolder?

Tags: java, json, compiler-errors

Inside my package `alignmentparser` I have a class named `Subject` where I have a string I want to convert to a JSON object. After researching how I might achieve this, I found the package [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java), which I downloaded and placed into my package as a subdirectory named `JSON`.

My classes' package statements state `package alignmentparser;`. I updated the package statements in each file in the JSON subdirectory to `package alignmentparser.JSON;`.

Now I can't get my `TestRunner` class (which depends on `Subject`) to compile. I get these error messages:

```
./alignmentparser/Subject.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
      ^   symbol:   class JSONObject   location: class Subject    
./alignmentparser/Subject.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
      ^   symbol:   class JSONObject   location: class Subject
```

What can I do to get past these error messages?

EDIT: Here is the whole code, just in case there are errors I don't know about.

**Subject.java**

```
package alignmentparser;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Subject {
  private String id;
  private String sequence;
  // Position on subject where alignment with query begins, inclusive 
  private int start;
  // Position on subject where alignment with query ends, inclusive
  private int end;

  public Subject(String accessNum, int hitFrom, int hitTo, String seq) {
    id = accessNum;
    sequence = seq;
    start = hitFrom;
    end = hitTo;
    getEntireSubject();
  }

  // Getters
  public String getSequence() {
    return sequence;
  }
  public int getStart() {
    return start;
  }
  public int getEnd() {
    return end;
  }

  // Fetches accession number from NCBI
  // https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25498/#chapter3.Application_2_Converting_access
  private void getEntireSubject() {
    try {
      // e post to Entrez
      String link = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/epost.fcgi?db=nucleotide&id=" + id;
      URLConnection connection = new URL(link).openConnection();
      connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
      connection.connect();
      BufferedReader r  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

      String webEnv = "";
      String queryKey = "";
      // Put together string to be scanned to find patterns
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
      }
      String result = sb.toString();
      // Specify patterns to search for
      String queryKeyRegEx = "<QueryKey>(\\d+)<\\/QueryKey>";
      String webEnvRegEx = "<WebEnv>(\\S+)<\\/WebEnv>";
      // Create Pattern objects
      Pattern queryKeyPattern = Pattern.compile(queryKeyRegEx);
      Pattern webEnvPattern = Pattern.compile(webEnvRegEx);
      // Create Matcher objects
      Matcher queryKeyMatcher = queryKeyPattern.matcher(result);
      if (queryKeyMatcher.find()) {
        queryKey = queryKeyMatcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(queryKey);
      }
      Matcher webEnvMatcher = webEnvPattern.matcher(result);
      if (webEnvMatcher.find()) {
        webEnv = webEnvMatcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(webEnv);
      }

      // e fetch to Entrez
      link = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=nucleotide&query_key="+queryKey+"&WebEnv="+webEnv+"&usehistory=y";
      connection = new URL(link).openConnection();
      connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");
      connection.connect();
      r  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

      sb = new StringBuilder();
      while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
      }
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
      System.out.println(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
package alignmentparser;

import java.util.*;

class TestRunner {
  private String query = "ATCCTGTCTGTGTTAGGAG-AGTCTACTTC-TTAACNGAGGGATTCANTNTTTCCTGCANAGGCGGCCGTCNATGAANACCCTGTTTGTGGACAGCTACNGNGAGATGCTTTTNTTTCTGCAGTCACTGTTCATGCTGGCCACCGTGGTGCTGTACTTCANCCACCTCAAGGAGTATGTGGCTTCCATGGTATTCTCCCTGGCCTTGGGCTGGNCCAACATGCTCTACTACNCCCGCGGTTTCCAGCAGANGGGCATCTATGCCGTCATGATANANAANATGATCCTGAGAGACCTGTGCCGTTTCATGTTTGTCTACGTCGTCTTNTTGTTCGGNTTTTCCACAGCGGNGGTGACGCTGATTGAAGACGGNAANAATGACTCCCTGCCGTCTGAGTCCACGTCGCACAGGNGGNGGGGGCCTGCCTGCANGCCCCCCGATAGCTCCTACAACAGCCTGTACTCCACCTGCCTGGAGCTGTTCAAGTTCACCATCGGCATGGGCGACCTGGANTTCACTGANAACTATGACTTCAAGGCTGTCTTCATCATCCTGCTGCTGGCCTATGTAATTCTCACCTACATCCTCNTGCTCAACATGCTNATCGCCCTCNTGGGTGAGACTGTCAACAAGATCGCACAGNNAGAGCAAGAACATCTGGAANCTGCAGAGAGCCATCACCATCCTGNACACGGAGAAGAGCTTCCTTAAGTGCATGAGGAAGGCCTTCCGCTCAGGCAAGCTGCNTGCANGTGGGGTACACACCTGATGGCAAGGACGACTACCGG";
  private String midline = "||||||||||||||||||| |||||||||| ||  | |||||||||| | ||||||||| ||||||||||| ||||| ||||||||||||||||||||| | ||||||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| ||||||||||||||||| |||||||||||||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||| | || ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| ||||||| |||||||| ||||||||||||| ||||||||||||||||||||| || |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| || ||||||||||||||| ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| |||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| ||||||||||||| ||||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||  ||||||||||||||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||| ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| |||| ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||";
  private Subject subj = new Subject("NM_080704", 1710, 2495, "ATCCTGTCTGTGTTAGGAGGAGTCTACTTCTTTTTCCGAGGGATTCAGTATTTCCTGCAGAGGCGGCCGTCGATGAAGACCCTGTTTGTGGACAGCTACAGTGAGATGCTTTTCTTTCTGCAGTCACTGTTCATGCTGGCCACCGTGGTGCTGTACTTCAGCCACCTCAAGGAGTATGTGGCTTCCATGGTATTCTCCCTGGCCTTGGGCTGGACCAACATGCTCTACTACACCCGCGGTTTCCAGCAGATGGGCATCTATGCCGTCATGATAGAGAAGATGATCCTGAGAGACCTGTGCCGTTTCATGTTTGTCTACATCGTCTTCTTGTTCGGGTTTTCCACAGCGGTGGTGACGCTGATTGAAGACGGGAAGAATGACTCCCTGCCGTCTGAGTCCACGTCGCACAGGTGGCGGGGGCCTGCCTGCAGGCCCCCCGATAGCTCCTACAACAGCCTGTACTCCACCTGCCTGGAGCTGTTCAAGTTCACCATCGGCATGGGCGACCTGGAGTTCACTGAGAACTATGACTTCAAGGCTGTCTTCATCATCCTGCTGCTGGCCTATGTAATTCTCACCTACATCCTCCTGCTCAACATGCTCATCGCCCTCATGGGTGAGACTGTCAACAAGATCGCACAGG-AGAGCAAGAACATCTGGAAGCTGCAGAGAGCCATCACCATCCTGGACACGGAGAAGAGCTTCCTTAAGTGCATGAGGAAGGCCTTCCGCTCAGGCAAGCTGC-TGCAGGTGGGGTACACACCTGATGGCAAGGACGACTACCGG");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestRunner analyzer = new TestRunner();
    analyzer.identifyMismatches();
    analyzer.identifyResidue(547);
  }

  /**
  * Identifies the residue encoded by the codon at the specified codon count.
  */
  private void identifyResidue(int pos) {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> codons = assembleCodonMap();

    // Set base position of first codon in the CDS (to be retrieved from GenBank later)
    int posOfCDS = 276;
    // Adjust given codon count to account for any difference between CDS / query length
    // NOTE: Subtract 3 to account for conversion between codon count and base count
    int adjustedPos = (pos * 3) - (subj.getStart() - posOfCDS) - 3;
    System.out.println(adjustedPos + subj.getStart());

    if (adjustedPos < 0) {
      System.out.println("Codon " + pos + " is not viewable in this alignment.");
      //System.out.println("You can view codons " + (posFirstCodon + 1) + " through " + ((2495 - 276) / 3));
    } 

    // Get codon
    String found = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < query.length(); i += 3) {
      if (i == adjustedPos) {
        found = query.substring(i, i + 3);
        System.out.println(found + " at " + (i + subj.getStart()));
      }
    }

    // Identify residue that codon translates to
    for (String codon : codons.keySet()) {
      if (codons.get(codon).contains(found)) {
        System.out.println("Residue is " + codon);
      }
    }
  }


  private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> assembleCodonMap() {
    ArrayList<String> ala = new ArrayList<String>();
    ala.add("GCT");
    ala.add("GCC");
    ala.add("GCA");
    ala.add("GCG");
    ArrayList<String> arg = new ArrayList<String>();
    arg.add("CGT");
    arg.add("CGC");
    arg.add("CGA");
    arg.add("CGG");
    arg.add("AGA");
    arg.add("AGG");
    ArrayList<String> asn = new ArrayList<String>();
    asn.add("AAT");
    asn.add("AAC");
    ArrayList<String> asp = new ArrayList<String>();
    asp.add("GAT");
    asp.add("GAC");
    ArrayList<String> cys = new ArrayList<String>();
    cys.add("TGT");
    cys.add("TGC");
    ArrayList<String> gln = new ArrayList<String>();
    gln.add("CAA");
    gln.add("CAG");
    ArrayList<String> glu = new ArrayList<String>();
    glu.add("GAA");
    glu.add("GAG");
    ArrayList<String> gly = new ArrayList<String>();
    gly.add("GGT");
    gly.add("GGC");
    gly.add("GGA");
    gly.add("GGG");
    ArrayList<String> his = new ArrayList<String>();
    his.add("CAT");
    his.add("CAC");
    ArrayList<String> ile = new ArrayList<String>();
    ile.add("ATT");
    ile.add("ATC");
    ile.add("ATA");
    ArrayList<String> leu = new ArrayList<String>();
    leu.add("TTA");
    leu.add("TTG");
    leu.add("CTT");
    leu.add("CTC");
    leu.add("CTA");
    leu.add("CTG");
    ArrayList<String> lys = new ArrayList<String>();
    lys.add("AAA");
    lys.add("AAG");
    ArrayList<String> met = new ArrayList<String>();
    met.add("ATG");
    ArrayList<String> phe = new ArrayList<String>();
    phe.add("TTT");
    phe.add("TTC");
    ArrayList<String> pro = new ArrayList<String>();
    pro.add("CCT");
    pro.add("CCC");
    pro.add("CCA");
    pro.add("CCG");
    ArrayList<String> ser = new ArrayList<String>();
    ser.add("TCT");
    ser.add("TCC");
    ser.add("TCA");
    ser.add("TCG");
    ser.add("AGT");
    ser.add("AGC");
    ArrayList<String> thr = new ArrayList<String>();
    thr.add("ACT");
    thr.add("ACC");
    thr.add("ACA");
    thr.add("ACG");
    ArrayList<String> trp = new ArrayList<String>();
    trp.add("TGG");
    ArrayList<String> tyr = new ArrayList<String>();
    tyr.add("TAT");
    tyr.add("TAC");
    ArrayList<String> val = new ArrayList<String>();
    val.add("GTT");
    val.add("GTC");
    val.add("GTA");
    val.add("GTG");

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> codons = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    codons.put("alanine", ala);
    codons.put("arginine", arg);
    codons.put("asparagine", asn);
    codons.put("aspartic acid", asp);
    codons.put("cysteine", cys);
    codons.put("glutamine", gln);
    codons.put("glutamic acid", glu);
    codons.put("glycine", gly);
    codons.put("histidine", his);
    codons.put("isoleucine", ile);
    codons.put("leucine", leu);
    codons.put("lysine", lys);
    codons.put("methionine", met);
    codons.put("phenylalanine", phe);
    codons.put("proline", pro);
    codons.put("serine", ser);
    codons.put("threonine", thr);
    codons.put("tryptophan", trp);
    codons.put("tyrosine", tyr);
    codons.put("valine", val);

    return codons;
  }


  /**
  * Prints out mismatches in the alignment of subject and query. 
  * Base positions are referenced from subject.
  */
  private void identifyMismatches() {
    // Loops through each character in the midline
    for (int i = 0; i < midline.length(); i++) {
      // If character is a space, denoting a mismatch
      if (midline.charAt(i) == ' ' && query.charAt(i) != 'N') {
        // Print out the characters at the same position in subject & query
        System.out.println(subj.getStart() + i);
        System.out.println(subj.getSequence().charAt(i) + ">" + query.charAt(i));
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

EDIT 2: Screenshot of my folder structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, unless you are planning to modify the source code for `JSON-java`, you don't really need to include the project as source code. Just modify your project dependency to include the JSON-java jar artifact or include it in your classpath so that the necessary classes can be found by the run time.

Secondly, if you really want to include the project as source code and compile it yourself, you still don't need to change the package structure of the project. You can compile it and build the artifact (jar) outside your application.

Thirdly, if you still want to include the project as source code in your own package, you need to modify the package declaration of each and every class within this project. It looks like you have already tried it. But to make sure you have, for example changed the package name of the class JSONObject from `org.json` to `alignmentparser.org.json`? Also, when you want to use one or more of these JSON-java classes in your own code, you need to import those classes. E.g. `import org.json.JSONObject`. I see in your code sample (Subject.java), that you are not doing it. Once you have fixed the package renaming and included the necessary class import statements, you should not get any compiler error.

Comment: I added `import alignmentparser.org.json.JSONObject` to `Subject.java`, but now I am getting another error (in addition to the original two errors) saying the package `alignmentparser.org.json` does not exist? I have renamed my subdirectory `org.json` and updated the package statements in each file to `package alignmentparser.org.json;`

Comment: Does your package directory alighmentparser contain directory org/json?

Comment: Yes, org.json is a directory inside the alignmentparser directory

Comment: Is there something I am missing in how I am setting up my package?

Comment: Aah, I see that your Subject.java is also inside the package alignmentparser. So do `import org.json.JSONObject` instead.

Comment: It still doesn't work, throwing `error: package org.json does not exist` :-/

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: Folder structure looks correct. Try adding the whole package path to your classpath. That must work.